# How to compute the orthonormal basis of a non square (rectangular) matrix

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix, orthogonal

I need to find a way of computing the orthonormal basis for range of a matrix. In matlab [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/orth.html) does it.

I need to do this in c/c++ and I am actually working with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/)

However, I haven't found anything that provides this capability in OpenCV.

I've tried working with cvSVD, but my results aren't correct.

Any clues?

Comment: Try octave instead: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/octave/octave_144.html

Comment: I've edited the question once it was not explicit enough. I'm doing this in c

Comment: SVD won't do it but Gram-Schmidt algorithm would do although I don't think OpenCV has the algorithm.

Comment: The answer posted by me below is a complete working algorithm in C++. To port it to C would be trivial.

Comment: @Dogbert I'll try to implement it tonight, I haven't set your answer as correct since I haven't had time to test it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in openCV, and it works with rectangular matrix as long as m>n, according to [this paper](http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~langou/publications/2005-CMA-giraud-langou-rozloznik.pdf)

```
- (CvMat *) buildOrthonormal:(CvMat *) matrix {

    NSInteger rows = matrix->rows;
    NSInteger cols = matrix->cols;

    CvMat *Q = cvCreateMat(rows, cols, kMatrixType);
    CvMat *R = cvCreateMat(cols, cols, kMatrixType);  

    for (NSInteger k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
        cvSetReal2D(R, k, k, 0.0f);

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            double value = cvGetReal2D(R, k, k) + cvGetReal2D(matrix, i, k) * cvGetReal2D(matrix, i, k);
            cvSetReal2D(R, k, k, value);
        }
        cvSetReal2D(R, k, k, sqrt(cvGetReal2D(R, k, k)));    

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            double value = cvGetReal2D(matrix, i, k) / cvGetReal2D(R, k, k);
            cvSetReal2D(Q, i, k, value);
        }

        for (NSInteger j = k + 1; j < cols; j++) {
            cvSetReal2D(R, k, j, 0.0f);
            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                double value = cvGetReal2D(R, k, j) + cvGetReal2D(Q, i, k) * cvGetReal2D(matrix, i, j);
                cvSetReal2D(R, k, j, value);
            }

            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                double value = cvGetReal2D(matrix, i, j) - cvGetReal2D(R, k, j) * cvGetReal2D(Q, i, k);
                cvSetReal2D(matrix, i, j, value);
            }
        }
    }
    cvReleaseMat(&R);

    return Q;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need an existing toolkit/library to handle this, @PureW above has provided a valid answer. If you need to implement this function yourself, you're looking for an implementation of the Gram-Schmidt algorithm.

Here is an example problem to help you verify your code:

http://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/Teaching/NAVC-SS11/sol_c8.pdf

And here is the code (please see references for full credits). PLEASE NOTE: This example assumes that you have a set of data that is scaled decently. If you have a poorly scaled matrix, you may need to consider LU-decomposition or an appropriate pivot strategy. There are useful links on this topic in the references as well.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

// example: http://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/Teaching/NAVC-SS11/sol_c8.pdf
// page 5

double a[3][3] = {
    {1.0, 2.0, 1.0},
    {0.0, 1.0, 2.0},
    {1.0, 2.0, 0.0}
};
// any column of a is a vector

double r[3][3], q[3][3];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int k, i, j;
    for (k=0; k<3; k++){
      r[k][k]=0; // equivalent to sum = 0
      for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        r[k][k] = r[k][k] + a[i][k] * a[i][k]; // rkk = sqr(a0k) + sqr(a1k) + sqr(a2k) 
      r[k][k] = sqrt(r[k][k]);  // ||a||
      cout << endl << "R"<<k<<k<<": " << r[k][k];

      for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
          q[i][k] = a[i][k]/r[k][k];
          cout << " q"<<i<<k<<": "<<q[i][k] << " ";
      }

      for(j=k+1; j<3; j++) {
        r[k][j]=0;
        for(i=0; i<3; i++) r[k][j] += q[i][k] * a[i][j];
        cout << endl << "r"<<k<<j<<": " <<r[k][j] <<endl;

        for (i=0; i<3; i++) a[i][j] = a[i][j] - r[k][j]*q[i][k];

        for (i=0; i<3; i++) cout << "a"<<j<<": " << a[i][j]<< " ";
      }
}

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**References:**

---

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/88888/
2. http://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/Teaching/NAVC-SS11/sol_c8.pdf
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element
4. http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/PivotingMod.html
5. http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FA9A48/index.html?solution=1-FA9A48

Comment: I think this example would be easier to understand if the input matrix wasn't square or '3' was to be used as 'rows' and 'cols'

Comment: True, but I did already acknowledge that this was someone else's code in the References section. Also, it's pretty easy to change the code accommodate different matrix sizes. Finally, the general algorithm itself has been presented, which is the bulk of the work.

Comment: sure, I understood that. Nonetheless, I need a version that works with any kind of matrix; still trying to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the [Gnu Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) which is a nice and well-tested library building on top of the BLAS-libraries. It implements a lot of different matrix operations and is usually where I would start for linear algebra stuff. Maybe one of [these](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/QR-Decomposition.html) would suit you?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab can generate codes.Why don't you try it???
First generate then examine and finally use it,that is all